# Немогу запустить проект glassfish + IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, java-ee, glassfish

Питаюсь подключить glassfish к IntelliJ IDEA но при запуске проекта возникает такая ошибка:

[2018-04-28 10:45:19,326] Artifact TestJSP4:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...

[2018-04-28 10:46:00,342] Artifact TestJSP4:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.

[2018-04-28 10:46:00,343] Artifact TestJSP4:war exploded: java.io.IOException: com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.faces.FacesException: Unable to find CDI BeanManager. Please see server.log for more details.

Уже 2 дня не могу понять что я не так делаю

Вот мой faces-config.xml

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<faces-config version="2.2" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd">

</faces-config>
```

Вот мой web.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: *Please see server.log for more details.*

Comment: Покажите ваш faces-config.xml и web.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте версию дескриптора развёртывания опустить до 3.1

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    ...
</web-app>
```